# Updating the src of an image through select-option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can i change the src of an image through select-option? The img-src is a php variable and once something is selected I wanted it to change a select-option from another div

**The dropdown**

```
<select>
<option value="<?php echo $aColorName; ?>">Color Name</option>
<option value="<?php echo $anotherColorName; ?>">Color Name</option>
</select>

<img src="<?php echo $colorUrl.$aColorName ?>" />
```

I wanted the image source to update each time a new color is selected from the options

Comment: Add the src as option value and put onchange = function(){document.querySelector('img').src = this.value}

Comment: @Lain mind elaborating? am kinda new, thanx

Comment: Why do we always complain when people make answers that should be comments, but we never say anything about comments that should be answers?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes because there is always a smart one who will eventually turn that comment into 'his own' answer.

Comment: @RST Hopefully I am not that person! LoL.

Comment: @RST yeah that happens a lot and I must admit that I used to do it in my first weeks as a StackOverflower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And a vanilla version...

```js
var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
    var theImg = document.getElementById('theImg');
    
    selectBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        theImg.src = '/images/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + '.jpg';
    }, false);
```

```html
<select id="selectBox">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>

<img id="theImg" src="/images/<?php echo $colorUrl.$aColorName ?>.jpg" />

<!--
The 'src' attribute in image below needs to point to the default image to fix your problem. So for example if your images path is: '/images/' and in your foreach loop the value of $colorUrl.$aColorName is: 'Yellow' then the above code will output thew following when the page initially loads:

<img id="theImg" src="/images/Yellow.jpg" />
-->
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.. btw the default and selected option after a page load is missing, it doesnt update it

Comment: No problem - do you mean, when the page first loads the image is broken? If yes, then there are many ways to fix this but simply set the initial value of the image src - <img id="theImg" src="/images/deafault.jpg" />

Comment: I tried doing that and it doesn't change the initial value

Comment: @atp Just curious to know, did you see my answer? Is there a specific reason you selected this, as I answered before this person?

Comment: It's a mess lol, basically I run a foreach php loop to find all the available colors and to 'echo' them out as options, everything works well except the selected option doesnt load but when I select an option and select it back it works.. just that it doesnt load.. adding the default image to src only puts it there and the code won't remove it

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, I'm a noob when it comes to js I appreciate your help but I understood Zinc's more clearly and I was able to integrate it to my code easily, thank you a lot Praveen, I appreciate your help

Comment: It just sounds like the problem described above, when the page loads you I guess are populating it like so right? <img id="theImg" src="<?php echo $colorUrl.$aColorName ?>" />

Comment: @Zinc no, I've left the src blank as yours

Comment: @atp Ironically I have a hard time to understand the `.addEventListener`. LoL. Different people with different views... Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have added jQuery, I will show you an example of **unobtrusive code** using event handlers.

```js
$(function () {
  $("select").change(function () {
    $("img").attr("src", "//placehold.it/250/" + this.value + "?text=" + $(this).find("option:selected").text());
  });
});
```

```css
img {display: block; margin: 15px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0f0">Yellow</option>
  <option value="00f">Blue</option>
</select>

<img src="//placehold.it/250?text=Select Colour" alt="" />
```

You can also do the same thing using Pure JS, by adding an event listener to the `onchange` event of the `<select>`.

Here, I have written some custom complicated code for setting the `src` attribute. In simple way, you can use the following to set the `value` of the selected option as the image's source:

```
$("img").attr("src", this.value);
```

Comment: instead of the placeholder.it can I change it a PHP variable?

Comment: I tried this too and it worked but I'm experiencing a problem, I have multiple bootstrap modals and each modal feeds your code a src and it displays it, but the problem is that when i close a modal and open another, I find the previous image.. it doesnt reset

Comment: @atp Looks like your issue is solved. But what I would say is to make something like demo-able. So that we can check. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I would love for you to see the website itself.. where can I send you the link?